# Getting started with Create React App - "Cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npm-start

I'm using the "Getting Started" guide because I've been experiencing endless errors trying to create a react app so far when following tutorials.

And straight away I'm running into a problem. When I run `npx create-react-app my-app` I get the following:

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
```

Can anyone advise me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Install CRA globally and then try.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I had previously uninstalled globally because that is what is advised on the "Getting started" guide.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a problem related with your node installation (maybe you removed manually create-react-app package?). I'd recommend following these steps:

1. Uninstall node and npm
2. Delete the npm cache and npm modules in your machine (In Windows machine you can usually find them at C:\Users\ {username} \AppData\Roaming\npm-cache and C:\Users\ {user name} \AppData\Roaming\npm) respectively.
3. Install node and npm again

If you really don't want to delete node and npm, try step 2 and see if that works. Following these steps did the job for me, hope that helps you.

Comment: worked for me too. Do not forget to delete the mentioned folders otherwise you have to do it twice like me

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue a few times. Every time I was searching thru net for a solution, and for every time i just typed in terminal

`npm i node`

and its just started working

Answer (score 0):

I think you might miss installing Node and npm in your machine.

Comment: Nope I definitely have node and NPM installed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install the library to clean the browser cache after React app updates by running:

```
npm install --save react-clear-cache
```

Then uninstall React globally, using

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then reinstall React globally again:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
```